# Rails validation on content type not working with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, content-type

I have a validation in my Rails (3.1.4) model to make sure no one tries to upload anything malicious in leiu of their profile image, but when I try to upload a jpeg, the validation is triggering.  I'm using the Paperclip gem and I'm unsure if that is having an impact.

validation in user.rb model

```
validates_attachment_content_type :profile_image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'], :message => "Only jpeg, gif and png files are allowed for profile pictures"
```

When I look at the properties of the jpeg locally (Windows O/S):

- Item type = JPEG image
- Type of file: JPEG image (.jpg)

Am I doing something wrong in my validation?

Also, when it triggers, it puts the model and field name before the message.  Is there a way to avoid that?  ie 'Profile image profile image content type Only jpeg, gif and png files are allowed for profile pictures'

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `'image/jpg'` to the content type array, I think that's what you're missing.